# Android Get Base URL of HTML app

Tags: android, apk

I have an app that is running on my phone that is simply displaying a web page. I'm trying to get the website name/info so that I can browse this on my desktop. I used Packet Sniffer to get the IP address but there are multiple hosts running on this IP. What's the best way for me to get the real URL/hostnames used by an Android app?

FYI: I've decoded the app but I still haven't figured out what the URL is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is, install the app in the emulator, and then use wireshark, which can handle http traffic.